# Unable to get subnet data using Terraform 0.12

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I am trying to query the values of the vpc and subnets, I was able to get the vpc id however I'm failing to get the subnet id's which are supposed to prove 2 values.

**Error is already seen on the terraform plan *(some details are removed to shorten your reading on my code)***

```
# module.environment.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.env will be created
  + resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "pogimo123" {
      + all_settings           = (known after apply)
      + application            = "pogimo123"
      + name                   = "pogimo123"
      + platform_arn           = (known after apply)
      + queues                 = (known after apply)
      + solution_stack_name    = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.8 running PHP 7.2"
      + tier                   = "WebServer"
      + setting {
          + name      = "ELBScheme"
          + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
          + value     = "internal"
        }
      + setting {
          + name      = "ELBSubnets"
          + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
          + value     = "data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids"
        }
      + setting {
          + name      = "Subnets"
          + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
          + value     = "data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids"
        }
      + setting {
          + name      = "VPCId"
          + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
          + value     = "vpc-pogimo123"
        }
    }
```

If you check on the VPC it shows the value was queried fine showing the vpc id **vpc-pogimo123** however on subnets I'm getting these

```
+ value     = "data.aws_subnet_ids.subnets.ids"
```

It is supposed to give this value

```
  + value   = [
            + "subnet-01293018398409233",
            + "subnet-jlkj312knasdhjalsd",
            + "subnet-908345mnsdfhs3244s",
    ]
```

**Here is the ERROR**

```
Error: ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: '["data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids"]' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'Subnets'): The subnet 'data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids' does not exist.
    status code: 400, request id: 123h12j3a-12312-4ed3458-c234-0adnahj234hjsa

  on ../modules/environment/tfenvtest.tf line 1, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest":
   1: resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
```

Here is the code I used

```
data "aws_vpc" "myvpc" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:POGIMO123"
    values = ["TRUE"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "mysubnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.myvpc.id

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["*_POGIMO123"]
  }
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "tftest" {
  name        = "pogimo123"
  description = "pogimo123"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.8 running PHP 7.2"
}

setting {
  namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
  name      = "VPCId"
  value     = data.aws_vpc.myvpc.id
}
setting {
  namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
  name = "ELBSubnets"
  value = "data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids"
}
setting {
  namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
  name = "Subnets"
  value = "data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to **verify** your script by launching it in my sandbox account in `us-east-1` and default VPC (not your custom VPC as there is no code for it provided).

There were **more issues** then it was initially apparent:

- `setting` must be in `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment`
- instead of `"data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids"` it should be `join(",", data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids)`
- missing instance profile

The modified and **fully working** terraform script for EB is as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  # your data
}

data "aws_vpc" "myvpc" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "mysubnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.myvpc.id
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "tftest" {
  name        = "pogimo123"
  description = "pogimo123"
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "eb_instance_role" {

  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eb_role_attachment" {

  role       = "${aws_iam_role.eb_instance_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier"
}



resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "eb_instance_profile" {

  role = "${aws_iam_role.eb_instance_role.id}"
  
  # wait for the profile to exist
  # it takes time
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 30"
  }
  
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.8 running PHP 7.2"
  

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = data.aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  }
  
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value     = aws_iam_instance_profile.eb_instance_profile.name
  }  

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "Subnets"
    value = join(",", data.aws_subnet_ids.mysubnets.ids)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Marcin - I already tried that, I also updated my question above by adding the error I encountered and the correction on the code (it should be mysubnets not subnets)

Comment: @Lagot i updated the answer with fully working version of your script.